# React forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs

i want to calculate the final total of the salary.when i add enter the data on the form data should append on the form and values are calculating and display the final total on the total textbox. when i enter the data and click submit button i got the error was

```
setUsers.forEach is not a function
TypeError: setUsers.forEach is not a function
```

what i tried so far i attached below.please rectify the eror

```
import { useState } from "react";


function Test() {
  
  const [name, setName] = useState();
    const [salary, setSalary] = useState();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    var [total, setTot] = useState();
  
    function Calculation()
{
  setUsers([...users,{ name, salary}]);
   
 

  users.forEach((user) => {
     newTotal += Number(user.salary);
  });
 
  setTot(newTotal);
}



    return (
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Employee Salary Calculation</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Employee Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Name"
     onChange={(event) =>
      {
          setName(event.target.value);      
      }}
    
    
    />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Salary</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Salary" 
    onChange={(event) =>
        {
            setSalary(event.target.value);      
        }}
    />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total" 
    onChange={(event) =>
        {
          setTot(event.target.value);      
        }}
    />
    </div>


   
<button type="submit" onClick={Calculation}  class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((row ) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{row .name}</td>
              <td>{row .salary}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
           
        
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
        
      </div>


    );
}
  
  export default Test;
```

[image]

i tried this

Comment: `setUsers` is a function, you probably want `users`

Comment: can you write the code it more helpful one

Comment: You want to show total salary in each row?

Comment: i attached the image above the i need to display total of each salary colum display on final total textbox

Comment: 45000 + 5500 display as the final total

Comment: It will be nice to use prettier for better readability :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setTot` to set total state and `reduce` function for total count instead `forEach`

```
function Calculation()
{
  setUsers([...users,{ name, salary}]);
   
  const total = users.reduce((total,user)=>{
    total += Number(user.salary)
    return total
  }),0);
  setTot(total); // you want this
}
```

Use `defaultValue` prop instead `value`

```
 <input type="text" defaultValue={total} class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total" 
    onChange={(event) =>
        {
          setTot(event.target.value);      
        }}
/>
```

Use `key` prop so react must understand which one to update

```
 {users.map((row,index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>{row.salary}</td>
            </tr>
  ))}
```

Comment: first time click the button value display 0 why

Comment: show me the any log users array

Comment: i have update the above my code please check

Comment: 0,45000,55000 i got the console

Comment: first value enter as 0 second value enter shown as firstvalue 45000 after 3 value enter as shown as second value

Comment: i think this is the log of total after each click. Try to log the users array value also, i want that

Comment: your last modify code i tried i got the error was on the console react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: I have updated the code, just use `key` prop

Comment: no man still wrong i havn't get the proper answer

Comment: 0,45000,55000 i got the console
when i enter the first value as 45000 it is not added become 0 again i added the secord value of 55000 then added the firstvalue 45000 why is that please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try

`users.forEach((user) => { total += user.salary; });`

instead of

`setUsers.forEach((users) => { total += users.salary; });`


`setUser` is the function which modifies the `users` state. You want to loop the users, not the function.

Comment: but no error total not display on the <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total" 
   value={total}            field why

Comment: total not display on the textfield

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use for each on the `users` state not on the `setUsers` setter.

`useState` hook return an Array which has two items, the variable which hold the state and a function to update that state value.

```
function Calculation()
{
    let sum = 0;

    users.forEach((user) => {
        sum+= user.salary;
    });

    setTot(sum)

    return sum;
}
```

Also you should have not defined `total` as that will be obtain after calling the `Calculation` function. Or you can call `setTot` to update the `totol` state once

Another point you could use `Array.prototype.reduce` function instead of `map` funciton. That will be like this

```
function calculation()
{
    let sum = users.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
        accumulator = accumulator + current.salary;
        return accumulator;
    }, 0);
    setTot(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: how to print on the textbox i tried this way  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total" 
   value={total}     but not working value didn't displayed

Comment: I've updated the response, If you want to use `total` state you could use a temporary variable in `calculation` function instead of  `total`. After that you call `setTot` to update `total` state